# sql.DB on aws-lambda too many connection

Tags: go, aws-lambda, connection-pooling

As I understand in Golang: `the DB handle is meant to be long-lived and shared between many goroutines`.

But when I using Golang with AWS lambda, it's a very different story since lambdas are stopping the function when it's finished.

I am using:`defer db.Close()` in Lambda Invoke function but it isn't affect. On MySQL, it's still keep that connection as `Sleep query`. As a result, it causes `too many connections` on MySQL.

Currently, I have to set `wait_timeout` in MySQL to small number. But it's not the best solution, in my opinion.

Is there any way to close connection when using Go SQL driver with Lambda?

Thanks,

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: Please share the code of your Lambda.

Comment: you should share mysql max connection settings too,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two problems that we need to address

- Correctly managing state between lambda invocations
- Configuring a connection pool

## Correctly managing state

Let us understand a bit of how the container is managed by AWS. From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html):

> After a Lambda function is executed, AWS Lambda maintains the
>   execution context for some time in anticipation of another Lambda
>   function invocation. In effect, the service freezes the execution
>   context after a Lambda function completes, and thaws the context for
>   reuse, if AWS Lambda chooses to reuse the context when the Lambda
>   function is invoked again.
>   This execution context reuse approach has the following implications:
>
> - Any declarations in your Lambda function code (outside the handler
>     code, see Programming Model) remains initialized, providing additional
>     optimization when the function is invoked again. For example, if your
>     Lambda function establishes a database connection, instead of
>     reestablishing the connection, the original connection is used in
>     subsequent invocations. We suggest adding logic in your code to check
>     if a connection exists before creating one.
> - Each execution context provides 500MB of additional disk space in the
>     /tmp directory. The directory content remains when the execution
>     context is frozen, providing transient cache that can be used for
>     multiple invocations. You can add extra code to check if the cache has
>     the data that you stored. For information on deployment limits, see
>     AWS Lambda Limits.
> - Background processes or callbacks initiated by your Lambda function
>     that did not complete when the function ended resume if AWS Lambda
>     chooses to reuse the execution context. You should make sure any
>     background processes or callbacks (in case of Node.js) in your code
>     are complete before the code exits.

This first bullet point says that state is maintained between executions. Let us see this in action:

```
let counter = 0

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  counter++
  callback(null, { count: counter })
}
```

If you deploy this and call multiple times **consecutively** you will see that the counter will be incremented between calls.

Now that you know that - you should not call `defer db.Close()`, instead you should be **reusing** the database instance. You can do that by simply making `db` a package level variable.

First, create a database package that will export an `Open` function:

```
package database

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

var (
    host = os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    port = os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
    user = os.Getenv("DB_USER")
    name = os.Getenv("DB_NAME")
    pass = os.Getenv("DB_PASS")
)

func Open() (db *gorm.DB) {
    args := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?parseTime=true", user, pass, host, port, name)
    // Initialize a new db connection.
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", args)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return
}
```

Then use it on your handler.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "github.com/<username>/<name-of-lib>/database"
)

var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    db = database.Open()
}

func Handler() (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    // You can use db here.
    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: 201,
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

**OBS**: don't forget to replace `github.com/<username>/<name-of-lib>/database` with the right path.

Now, you might still see the `too many connections` error. If that happens you will need a connection pool.

## Configuring a connection pool

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool):

> In software engineering, a connection pool is a cache of database
>   connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when
>   future requests to the database are required. Connection pools are
>   used to enhance the performance of executing commands on a database.

You will need a connection pool that the number of allowed connections must be equal to the number of parallel lambdas running, you have two choices:

- MySQL Proxy

> MySQL Proxy is a simple program that sits between your client and
>   MySQL server(s) and that can monitor, analyze or transform their
>   communication. Its flexibility allows for a wide variety of uses,
>   including load balancing, failover, query analysis, query filtering
>   and modification, and many more.

- AWS Aurora:

> Amazon Aurora Serverless is an on-demand, auto-scaling configuration
>   for Amazon Aurora (MySQL-compatible edition), where the database will
>   automatically start up, shut down, and scale capacity up or down based
>   on your application's needs. It enables you to run your database in
>   the cloud without managing any database instances. It's a simple,
>   cost-effective option for infrequent, intermittent, or unpredictable
>   workloads.

Regardless of your choice, there are plenty of tutorials on the internet on how to configure both.

Comment: Thanks for very detail answer. But you missed the most important note in lambda doc is " When you write your Lambda function code, do not assume that AWS Lambda automatically reuses the execution context for subsequent function invocations". Which means if you dont close your connection well, it will cause to my problems since the lambda will create new instance with new connection when needed without close the old.

Comment: That is not important really, you should only keep in mind that the connection will be automatically closed when a container shuts down.

Comment: sadly, it take 28,800 seconds, by default,  to automatically close. Means ur mysql will hold many useless connections which are highly potential shup yuor service down.

Comment: There is a difference between closing the request and closing the container. If you still see `too many connections` you need your own MySQL Proxy or use AWS Aurora instead.

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 was I helpful?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hel, I learnt somethings new from ur answer. But it doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 Are you still seeing `too many connections`? Did you create the MySQL Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answer here, if you are using `rows, err := db.Query(..)` anywhere in your code, you need to make sure to `defer rows.Close()`.

If you don't close the rows from a `db.Query()`, the connection will stay open in a sleeping state between lambda calls.